# JPA Sorting and Pagination

Tags: sorting, jpa, pagination

In my code I need to mount the select dynamically according to the parameterization of my system. For this I am setting up the following structure:

```
    StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
    final String numeroCadastro = "numeroCadastro";

    sql.append("select colaborador.id.numeroEmpresa, colaborador.id.tipoColaborador, colaborador.id.numeroCadastro as ").append(numeroCadastro).append(", colaborador.nome as nome, ");

    boolean sinalPositivo = false;
    String alias = "horasPagar";
    getSelectSumHorasCompensacao(sql, sinalPositivo, alias);

    sql.append(",");

    sinalPositivo = true;
    alias = "horasReceber";
    getSelectSumHorasCompensacao(sql, sinalPositivo, alias);

    sql.append(" from Colaborador colaborador, Situacao situacao ");

    sql.append(" where ");...
```

To mount the ordering snippet I add the "Order by" directly into the query string and set my limiters as follows:

```
 if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(orderByField)) {

        return " order by " + orderByField.replace("x.", aliasName);
    } else if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(defaultSort)) {
        return " order by " + aliasName + defaultSort;
    }
    .
    .
    .
 EntityManager persistenceContext = getPersistenceContext();

 TypedQuery<T> jpaQuery = persistenceContext.createQuery(sbSql.toString(), T);
 if (start != null && limit != null) {
            jpaQuery.setFirstResult(start);
            jpaQuery.setMaxResults(limit);
        }

        List<Object[]> resultList = jpaQuery.getResultList();
```

However doing so is set up a select command that does not paginate properly by considering the line number of my main select without considering that it is paged. Below is the command generated with the parts that the JPA inserts to make the pagination:

[select generated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3WYD.png)

Here is the result of my select already ordered, without the paging generated by the JPA

[Main select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ZQ1E.png)

Here the result generated with the pagination. Note that because of the pagination the first 10 records are not the same. From what I understand this happens because it is based on the ROWNUM of my main query and brings only rows smaller than 10.

[Result with pagination](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xaeUx.png)

My question is, how do JPA page the result correctly considering the ordering of my select?

Answer (score 0):

I realized my mistake. In the ordering I am performing I have placed only one column that contained several equal values. In these sections I believe that Oracle itself ordered the records according to the return. To fix it I added a key field in ordering and this brought the records correctly.